# Can you identify this Ninjago set from an assembly from it?

Tags: set-identification, ninjago

We got handed down 5000 LEGO bricks with no instructions. This small section was already put together. Please help identify what set it's from. I think it's a plane.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [Plate 4X4 W/Angle](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4561038) in White

This is from

[70009-1: Worriz's Combat Lair](https://brickset.com/sets/70009-1/Worriz-s-Combat-Lair)

[image]

And is part of the tail section of the helicopter

[image]

Comment: Wow you are amazing thank you so much now to find all the other pieces

Answer (score 0):

70009-1 Chima: Worriz's Combat Lair. From 2013 and Chima Season 1. But I think that you might be overestimating because the Combat Lair only has 664 parts. There are only about 30 sets at the time of writing with over 5000 components.